# Font Face not working in Firefox or IE

Tags: css, html, font-face

I don't really get what is going on.

I'm using Font Squirrel's @Font Face Packs and its not working in **Firefox** and **IE**, but it works perfectly in **Chrome** and in **Android's browser**, I haven't tried Safari. And these packs are supposed to work seamlessly, that's the whole point of them, but its not.

So here's my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/Fonts/Orotund-fontfacekit/Orotund.css" type="text/css"/>
```

and

```
p{
font-family: OrotundHeavy,Georgia,Serif;
}
```

This is only effecting the font in Chrome, 
You can see it here

Thanks in advance.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OrotundHeavy';
    src: url('Orotund-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Orotund-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Orotund-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Orotund-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Orotund-webfont.svg#OrotundHeavy') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OrotundCapitalsHeavy';
    src: url('OrotundCaps-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OrotundCaps-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OrotundCaps-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OrotundCaps-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('OrotundCaps-webfont.svg#OrotundCapitalsHeavy') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: 404 for me when I try that link. Post the real code instead of the reference to it...

Comment: em sorry about that took out a '-' by accident, I updated the link and put the code there too

Comment: Did you try `font-face: 'OrotundHeavy'` (with quotes)?

Comment: Yeah just did there, no change

Comment: the link http://testerwebby.tumblr.com/ shows me the custom font properly.

Comment: Does the `demo.html` file shipped with the Font Squirrel pack work?

Comment: @BastianRang what browser? Em the demo.html doesn't work because its not linked to the stylesheet, but that shouldn't make any difference to how mine works should it?

Comment: The problem is with firefox and IE, chrome works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Same here (404) by direct access.

Have you noticed the error you get in Firefox?

Timestamp: 12/06/03 14:42:19
Error: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): **bad URI or cross-site access not allowed**
source: https://www.dropbox.com/static/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf
Source File: https://www.dropbox.com/static/css/main.css
Line: 0
Source Code:
@font-face {   font-family: "Open Sans";   font-style: normal;   font-weight: 400;   src: url("/static/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/static/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/static/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/static/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular") format("svg"); }

Comment: em sorry about that took out a '-' by accident, I updated the link and put the code there too.